# Unable to reference one particular variable declared outside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scope

I'm trying to animate a projectile motion path using Python. To achieve this I'm using matplotlib's animation module. My full script is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math
import sys

import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show

# Gravitational acceleration in m/s/s
g = -9.81
# Starting velocity in m/s.
vel = 100
# Starting angle in radians.
ang = 45 * math.pi / 180
# Starting height in m.
y0 = 0
# Time settings.
t = 0
dt = 0.1
time = -vel**2 * math.sin(2 * ang) / g

def projectile():
    print g, vel, ang, y0, dt, time
    print t # Crashes here with UnboundLocalError: local variable 't' referenced before assignment
    t=0 # With this it works
    x = 0
    y = 0.1
    xc = []
    yc = []

    # Simulate the projectile.
    while t < time:
        x = vel * math.cos(ang) * t
        y = vel * math.sin(ang) * t + (g * t**2) / 2 + y0
        if y < 0:
            break
        t += dt
        xc.append(x)
        yc.append(y)
        yield x, y

def update_frame(sim):
    x, y = sim[0], sim[1]
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# Show the results.
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([-5,1500])
ax.set_ylim([0,300])

# ax.plot returns a single-element tuple, hence the comma after line.
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro', ms=5)
ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=update_frame, frames=projectile, blit=True, interval=20, init_func=init, repeat=False)
show()
```

The problem I have is that I seem to be able to use every variable, except `t`. I did it to create a stop condition so it would run only once and I later found out about `repeat=False`, but I'm still curious about this. Why can't I use `t` inside `projectile`? I am running Python 2.7.6 with Matplotlib 1.3.1 from the Anaconda 1.9.1 package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because you try to **reassign** the global variable `t`.

The variables `g, vel, ang, y0, dt, time` you only access (without reassigning them), so python tries to access them both locally and then globally. However, when you **reassign** `t` with the line `t += dt`, you are really telling python to create a local variable with the identifier `t` and assign it the desired value. Therefore, the global identifier `t` cannot be accessed as you've told python that `t` is local, and when you try to access `t` before it is assigned, you the `UnboundLocalError` is raised.

To tell python to reassign `t` as a global variable, you simply need to add `global t` to the beginning of your function:

```
t = 0
(..)
def projectile():
    print g, vel, ang, y0, dt, time
    global t # now t can be edited as a global variable
    print t #works
    x = 0
    y = 0.1
    xc = []
    yc = []

    while t < time:
        (..)
        t += dt
```

**EDIT:**

As *flebool* pointed out, you can actually still change a global variable as long as you don't reassign the identifier for it. For example, the code below is valid:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> def changelist():
...    l.append(4)
...
>>> changelist()
>>> l
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: This is very misleading. The problem is not in changing the variable `t`, but in assigning the identifier `t` to something else. For example If you take `t=numpy.array([0,3])` defined at the top, and then you try to change `t[1]`  within `projectile()` without declaring it `global`, it will still work.

Comment: @flebool Thank you, you're right. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well done. I'd say that the citation from the link is still misleading and I would get rid of it, but this is just my opinion

Comment: @flebool No, I agree - citations just look so great, so I was trying my best to keep it. ;)